# Suppress remix `ErrorResponseImpl` errors

Tags: express, remix.run

I am running remix from an express server with nodejs

When a route is not found, I see in the console:

```
ErrorResponseImpl {
  status: 404,
  statusText: 'Not Found',
  internal: true,
  data: 'Error: No route matches URL "/favicon.ico"',
  error: Error: No route matches URL "/favicon.ico"
      at getInternalRouterError (/Users/dangoodman/code/node-express-remix-template/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:4487:5)
      at Object.query (/Users/dangoodman/code/node-express-remix-template/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:2933:19)
      at handleDocumentRequestRR (/Users/dangoodman/code/node-express-remix-template/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:180:35)
      at requestHandler (/Users/dangoodman/code/node-express-remix-template/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:105:24)
      at /Users/dangoodman/code/node-express-remix-template/node_modules/@remix-run/express/dist/server.js:41:28
}
```

I have the following code in my `entry.server.tsx` which catches certain logs, but this is not something I am logging.

```
export function handleError(
  error: any,
  { request, params, context }: LoaderFunctionArgs | ActionFunctionArgs
) {
  if (!request.signal.aborted && !error.data?.includes("No route matches URL")) {
    logger.error(
      {
        err: extractError(error),
      },
      "unhandled remix error"
    )
  }
}
```

and call remix from express like

```
app.all("*", createRequestHandler({ build: build as any }))
```

Previously, setting NODE_ENV=production stopped this output, but it seems that either something else stopped it previously or it has come back.

How can I stop these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `ErrorBoundary` in `root.tsx` stopped the error.

`NODE_ENV=production` stopped the `No routes...` log line